# How to add column to table?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

Using "react-native-sqlite-storage" the application is already live on Google Play. I want to add two columns to an existing database table in such a way the application will not crash for existing users.

Answer (score 0):

When you will add column to existing table you will get error like

```
error: {"message":"no such column: todoStar","code":5} // todoStar is column name
```

In error block you can alter the table and add your column. Make sure you write the code inside error block

```
  if (error.message.indexOf('no such column: todoStar') > -1) {
          dbConnection.transaction(function (tx2) {
            let query = 'ALTER TABLE todos ADD todoStar Int(32);'; // todos is tableName
            tx2.executeSql(
              query,
              '',
              async (tx3) => {
                console.log('new column added');
              },
              (error) => {
                console.error(
                  'error: while adding column' + JSON.stringify(error),
                );
              },
            );
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual official documentation only contains basic information, and there is not much information on migration or database upgrades.

After hours of long research, I found that SQLite has `user_version` which can be used to know which version the user currently has, based on that we can execute upgrade queries.

I am using `expo-sqlite`, but the below solution should also work for `react-native-sqlite-storage`

Example:

```js
/** database.tsx **/

export function getUserDBVersion() {
  return new Promise<SQLite.SQLResultSet>((resolve, reject) => {
    database.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `PRAGMA user_version`,
        [],
        (_, res) => {
          resolve(res);
        },
        (_, error) => {
          reject(error);
          return true;
        }
      );
    });
  });
}

export function updateUserDBVersion(version: number) {
  return new Promise<SQLite.SQLResultSet>((resolve, reject) => {
    database.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `PRAGMA user_version = ?`,
        [version],
        (_, res) => {
          resolve(res);
        },
        (_, error) => {
          reject(error);
          return true;
        }
      );
    });
  });
}
```

```js
/** App.tsx **/

useEffect(() => {
  getUserDBVersion().then((res) => {
    const user_version = res.rows._array[0].user_version;
    if (user_version < 1) {
      //User has old version
      //(1) Run function to upgrade your database tables
      alterTables().then(() => {
        //(2) Update user_version so that next time you can check if < 2 for new updates
        updateUserVersion(1);
      });
    }
  });
}, []);
```

I think this is an elegant way for 2 reasons

1. You can update all of your databases and tables in one place
2. You can display the splash screen until all this migration is completed

**For readability I have not added error handling part above*

**Most of the above code will be the same for `react-native-sqlite-storage`, if not update your code accordingly*

**The above code is in typescript, simply remove types if you are using **jsx***